UICollectionviewCell when scroll horizonatlly to next page only half cell is display
I am using UICollectionView, where It should works like carousel.I want to display some part of previous cell - current cell - some part of next cell. I have played around with item size and sectionInsets- Left and Right, but nothing works. I revert all the trials and start from the scratch. Can you please suggest what I supposed to change to make it work.
let mainCarouselCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mainCarouselCollectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    mainCarouselCollectionView.dataSource = self
    mainCarouselCollectionView.tag = 0
    view.addSubview(mainCarouselCollectionView)
  
    
    startTimerForMainCarousel(scrollTime: 2)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    let mainCollectionViewFlowControl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.itemSize = CGSize(width: width - 10, height: 218)
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    //mainCollectionViewFlowControl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    mainCollectionViewFlowControl.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left:5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    self.mainCarouselCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = mainCollectionViewFlowControl
    

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 6

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let carouselCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
        for: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell
        else { fatalError("Cannot create new cell") }


     let subViews = carouselCell.parentView.subviews
        for subview in subViews{

            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let carouselView : UIView = UIView()
        
        carouselView.frame.origin.x = 4
        carouselView.frame.origin.y = 4
        carouselView.frame.size.height = carouselCell.parentView.frame.size.height - 8
        carouselView.frame.size.width = carouselCell.parentView.frame.size.width - 8
        carouselView.backgroundColor = .blue
        carouselCell.parentView.addSubview(carouselView)

        
        return carouselCell
}


func startTimerForMainCarousel(scrollTime: Int ) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        
        self.mainCarouselTimer?.invalidate()
        self.mainCarouselTimer = nil
        self.mainCarouselTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(scrollTime), target: self, selector: #selector(automaticScrollMainCarousel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
   
}

@objc func automaticScrollMainCarousel() {
    
    if mainCarouselCounter < mainCarouselArray.count - 1 {
        mainCarouselCounter += 1
        mainCarouselCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: mainCarouselCounter, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    } else {
        mainCarouselCounter = 0
        mainCarouselCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: mainCarouselCounter, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }

}



class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
let parentView = UIView()
static let reuseIdentifier = "cell-reuse-identifier"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("not implemented")
}

func configure() {
    parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(parentView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        parentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        parentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        parentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}

}


You should start where you have a cell in middle and 2 cell display their half part
Then you you know cell size and spacing between
After that modify section index

